# Plotting colorbar with Basemap and Matplotlib error

Tags: python, matplotlib, netcdf, matplotlib-basemap, colorbar

I made a prototype of application that plots wrf data using python and display the figures on a web interface as a project of my internship. I made it on my local computer and it worked well, but when I tried to install my application and make it work on the server I got this error :

```
AttributeError: 'Basemap' object has no attribute 'colorbar'
```

I have no clue where it comes from since I installed all required libraries sucessfully and the colorBar worked previously on my local computer.
Here is the source code where I got the error :

```
 m = Basemap(width=700000,height=700000,
            resolution='l',projection='stere',\
            lat_ts=40,lat_0=lat_0,lon_0=lon_0) 
        xi, yi = m(lons, lats)
        cs = m.pcolor(xi,yi,variable)
        m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80., 81., 10.), labels=[1,0,0,0], fontsize=10)
        m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180., 181., 10.), labels=[0,0,0,1], fontsize=10)
        m.drawcoastlines()
        m.drawstates()
        m.drawcountries()

        cs.get_cmap().set_over('0.25')
        cs.get_cmap().set_under('0.75')
        norm = cs.get_cmap().N
        cbar = m.colorbar(cs, location='bottom', pad="10%")
        cbar.set_label("C")
```

The 2 last lines triggered the error.

Comment: Use `plt.colorbar(...)` instead...?

Comment: It seem to work this way but I still wondering why my code above don't work because I used the basemap documentation to make it : http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html

Comment: You're right, that's very odd. Any chance that the server uses an older version of `mpl_toolkits.basemap`? It might have been added recently (the online manual doesn't mention the version it was added).